# How to get best possible resolution for camera photo using HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, camera, html5-video, photo

I found this one https://webrtchacks.github.io/WebRTC-Camera-Resolution/ It is about the video and I assume that resolution for photo can be much better than for video for the same camera.

Is there a way to check camera's best resolution and make a photo? (using HTML and JavaScript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video and photos are essentially the same thing. There isn't really a "take photo" API like there is a difference on your physical camera or phone.

To take a photo, you just turn on the video camera for a second, save a still frame, and then that is your photo.

Thus, everything that applies for video applies for photo.

Answer (score 0):

Just use HTML `<input type='file' accept='image/*' capture='camera'>` via a mobile device (not a desktop); you can then manipulate the result to change the resolution as required via a javascript canvas.